# How Do I scrape Multiple pages and write data into excel

Tags: web-scraping, python-3.6

How to sprape multiple pages in excel.
for example i want to scrape "http://econpy.pythonanywhere.com/ex/001.html"
how to scrape next pages considering number of pages are unknown

Plus i have written a code it prints nonetype in excel but not the data

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

page_url = "http://econpy.pythonanywhere.com/ex/001.html"
new_file = "Mynew.csv"
f = open(new_file, "w")
Headers = "Header1, Header2\n"
f.write(Headers)


html = urlopen(page_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
buyer_info = soup.find_all("div", {"title":"buyer-info"})
for i in buyer_info:
    Header1 = i.find("div", {"title":"buyer-name"})
    Header2 = i.find("span", {"class":"item-price"})
    salmon = print(Header1.get_text())
    salam = print(Header2.get_text())
    f.write("{}".format(salmon)+ "{}".format(salam))
f.close()
```

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try and let me know if you have any issues. I used "css selector" and "requests" for the operation to be accomplished.

```
import csv ; import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

outfile = open('Mynew.csv', 'w',newline='')
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(["Name","Price"])

for page in range(1,6):
    html = requests.get("http://econpy.pythonanywhere.com/ex/00{0}.html".format(page))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html.parser")
    for item in soup.select("div[title=buyer-info]"):
        Header1 = item.select_one("div[title=buyer-name]").get_text()
        Header2 = item.select_one("span.item-price").get_text()
        writer.writerow([Header1, Header2])
        print(Header1,Header2)
outfile.close()
```

Comment: since pages are known here what if we have n number of pages? like not known?then in that what we can do?

Comment: and how to use css selector?

Comment: it is good.....this is what i was looking for .........now please tell me since pages are known here what if we have n number of pages? like not known?then in that what we can do? and and how to use css selector?

Comment: Track this link down. You will learn how to use css selectors: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 0):

i got it solved till 1st page... and this is the code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

page_url = "http://econpy.pythonanywhere.com/ex/001.html"
new_file = "Mynew.csv"
f = open(new_file, "w")
Headers = "Header1,Header2\n"
f.write(Headers)

html = urlopen(page_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser") 
buyer_info = soup.find_all("div", {"title":"buyer-info"})
for i in buyer_info:
    Header1 = i.find("div", {"title":"buyer-name"})
    Header2 = i.find("span", {"class":"item-price"})
    f.write('{},{}\n'.format(Header1.text, Header2.text))
f.close()
```

now the pain comes how to spacre for mulitple pages , means how to scrape next pages also?

Comment: You can create a loop which will run until encounters 404 response status and put a break there so that when it is done the scraper will run no more in case you wanna deal with unlimited or unknown page numbers. Something like "if response.status_code == 404: break" . You opened this thread with two questions and when you have got those solved then again keep making new questions. Why?

Comment: Just for knowledge. Thank you so much for your help